# keep assets folder in proguard Android

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8

I'm using **proguard** to obfuscate my code, and I have one module called a library and in that module I have an **assets** folder and I'm keeping some jars that I'm using in runtime.
I want to keep that assets folder in the proguard.

Here is how it's looking the structure:

[image]

How can I keep these? or How can we pass the path of the file in **ProGuard**?

Comment: Did you found solution? I am also looking for the same.

Comment: I have this issue too.

Answer (score 2):

To keep directory we can use this in dexguard rules:

```
-keepdirectories mydirectory/*
```

or just keep exactly the resource: (worked for assets in aar):

```
-keepresourcefiles */myFile.bar
```

Comment: keepresourcefiles option is not there in the proguard file.  How do we get the directory for the assets folder?

Comment: I used this in dexguard.